# Delphi memory leakage: Does calling SomeForm.Free free up all dynamically allocated memory assigned during use of that instance of the form?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

Say we have a Delphi application which creates an instance of a form- SomeForm, which has a few Label objects on it and a few class objects created to store data (some of which is not on the program's stack, including some dynamic arrays of objects).

When we call SomeForm.free from the parent form, is all the memory allocated during the use of SomeForm freed up?

Comment: UI objects that were dropped on a form and other components which were created with form as owner will be released automatically. For other data it depends on whether you have written cleanup code in the form destructor or `OnDestroy` event handler. You would have to provide [mcve] which shows how you create and free those objects and their declarations.

Comment: If the objects you create are derived from TComponent and the constructor argument is the form, then yes, when the form is free, the component instance will be. But if the object you create are "simple" objects such a TStringList, then you have to free it yourself when you don't need it anymore, for example from the form's destructor or OnDestroy event handler. There is a lot to say about object life cycle management in Delphi!

Comment: In addition to previous comments, you can also force a report of eventual memory leaks by adding `  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;` immediately after `begin` in the .dpr file.

Comment: The only things freed automatically when a form is destroyed are controls that have been assigned the form as their owner. Everything else that was allocated (created) is your responsibility to free.